# How to Cloud Firestore Data Sort by Desc SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, swiftui, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch the data from my `Firestore` collection and now what i want to do is to sort the documents by one of the fields say "dateCode" Attaching codes below:

```
func getDescOrderData(completion: @escaping ([String:Any]) -> Void) {
    var dictInfo = [String:Any]()
    Firestore..collection("OldData").order(by: "dateCode", descending: true)
        .whereField("dateCode", isLessThanOrEqualTo: “Mon”)
        .whereField("studentId", isEqualTo: self.studentId)
        .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Old History Data error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                        dictInfo.append(document.data())
                }
                completion(dictInfo)
            }
        }
}
```

But i got error given below:-

`Old History Data error`: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.googl.................

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is trying to use query which needs so called [Composite Index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes). Actually according to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) it should be possible by the link that is in the error massage:

> If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map
> to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes
> a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

Just open it in browser and create the index. That's all! :)